# Detecting if a running application is sandboxed

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, sandbox, core-foundation

Given an application's pid, is there any way, programatically, of detecting if that application is running in an OSX sandbox environment?

Ideally, I'd like to know if there's an API call somewhere, preferably in C, rather than objective-C (for a daemon, so not using Cocoa), but if not, is there any other way of checking?

Comment: There's probably a CoreFoundation call you could use.

Comment: @Linuxios, I thought they might be, but do you know what would be, I've not found one yet?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but for security reasons, normally there shouldn't be a way.

Comment: @Medinoc, if the requesting app were in a sandbox, then I'd agree with you, but it's not. For example, Activity Monitor has a Sandbox column that displays this information, so it must be available somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Linuxios was right partly right about there being a CoreFoundation call. In fact, there are a few that when combined, can be used to solve this and it's based on the call to **SecStaticCodeCheckValidityWithErrors**

For anyone that may want, or need to programmatically test for an app being sandboxed can follow [this blog](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/checking-code-signing-and-sandboxing-status-in-code/).

Also, the full code to the article has been added to Github [here](https://github.com/ole/NSBundle-OBCodeSigningInfo).

Answer (score 1):

First you must get the path of the application from the pid, and then you can use the command `codesign --display --entitlements - app_path` to view all the entitlements. If the app has the entitlements com.apple.security.app-sandbox set to true then it is sandboxed.

You can take a look [here](http://oleb.net/blog/2012/02/checking-code-signing-and-sandboxing-status-in-code/).

Comment: Thanks, although I'd rather a function call, as I don't really want to be parsing the output from a system call. If Apple were to change the name of the entitlement, my daemon would stop functioning correctly. I know I could also use the asctl command, which prints out 'running with App Sandbox enabled', but am trying not to use that for the same reason.

Comment: codesign also accepts pid as an argument, so there's no need to start by finding the path from the pid.

Answer (score 0):

For detecting the sandbox in Flex/AIR/AS3 you can use the following kludge. The same approach should also work in objc. The only condition under which this would not work would be if the Documents folder were entirely empty. Or you could use any other folder that is off-limits to the sandbox.

```
            var file:File = File.userDirectory;
            var a:Array = file.nativePath.split("/");
            var userName:String = a[2];
            var docFolder:File = new File("/Users/" + userName + "/Documents/");
            var dirList:Array = docFolder.getDirectoryListing();
            if (dirList.length>0) {
                docDirectoryDisplay.text = "App is NOT sandboxed.";
            } else {
                docDirectoryDisplay.text = "App is sandboxed.";
            }
```

Comment: What is "File"?